# How to stop a brush from darkening the color of a previous stroke?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, painting

[image: I have an image here] In the image above, I showcase the problem.

I have some marker brushes that have a nice texture on them which shows the tooth of the paper. I'd like to get a more consistent look when I'm coloring in an area, but when I go over the same area in more than one stroke, the paint darkens (Example #1). In example #2 I went over the same area, but within the same stroke. The color stays consistent in that case. This is the effect I want, but with multiple strokes. In example #3 I tried fixing the problem by selecting the area around the initial stroke with the magic wand and painting it in, but that leaves a white outline over the original stroke. Expanding the selection by 1 pixel results in a dark line between the strokes.

So is there a way to solve this problem so that I get a smooth, consistent look with multiple strokes, like in example #2 Where I only use 1 stroke?

Comment: You could open the brushes panel and make sure the opacity is set to 100%.

Comment: Open Panel Brushes, and check values. Wet edges, Opacities, etc. could changes this behaviour.

Comment: @Johannes Yup, it definitely is. I think the brush just has some lower opacity built into it for the texture. I'm wondering why going over the same area with one stroke is fine, but not two.

Comment: Make sure that your brush mode is in 'normal'. and change you brush settings 'opacity jitter' and 'flow jitter' to 0% if it is not.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a Brush that has transparency built into it. There's no way around that effect as a result without opening the .abr file and adjusting the opacity of the stroke which would defeat the purpose of using that brush to begin with.

For example here is a Watercolor Brush on white background:

[image]

If I remove the white background even though the brush flow and opacity is 100% you can see it contains different levels of transparency within the actual brush:

[image]

Your best bet is what you did in number two combined with masks to control the form.

Answer (score 1):

This problem annoyed me for a long ass time. Just now I found the ONLY solution:

1. Open the tool properties for the brush.
2. Go to ink.
3. Change blending mode to "compare density".

FINALLY I frickin found it !!!

Comment: Note the **Compare Density** option is only available in very new versions of Photoshop (2021+). As this is a 2015 question, it was *not* an option in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I had good luck using the airbrush setting on my paintbrush:

[image]

Might not be the be-all, end-all solution, but it's worked so far for me.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your main opacity and flow settings (in top bar) are both at 100% and that the opacity percentage (transparency) is only adjusted within the layer

Answer (score 0):

*Well I had the same problem but its not related with the op or anything.When you to go the brush presets there is an option called wet edges if its marked brush will overlap and if not it will give u the pure color hope that helps
Peace*

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off pen pressure for opacity (located next to brush opacity) and wet edges (in brush panel). This should keep the opacity brush strokes consistent, which should solve this problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this problem: checked my opacity, multiply effect on brush etc. turned out I had a "curves layer" laying on top of everything (with each layer ordered in "pass through"-folders) incrementing the contrast for each layer. So stupid yet easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a layer that's customised to have an opacity below 70% or 60%.

adobe PS doesn't have those kinds of modes

Answer (score -1):

Make the brush flow equal to 100%. This is on the top bar beside the size, opacity, and other settings. If this does not work make sure your opacity is up to 100%. You can try making a new layer and painting your next stroke on that layer. Attempt to put the blending mode on add if this does not work still. Keep troubleshooting.

Comment: I tried that, but the effect is the same as example #1.

Comment: I have added more solutions to my answer, refresh.

Comment: Hmmm. It looks the same to me. It says make flow 100%. I did that, but I think that's only for one stroke, not multiple.

Comment: Nope, refresh again because I wrote: Make the brush flow equal to 100%. This is on the top bar beside the size, opacity, and other settings. If this does not work make sure your opacity is up to 100%. You can try making a new layer and painting your next stroke on that layer. Attempt to put the blending mode on add if this does not work still. Keep troubleshooting.

Comment: Opacity was already at 100. Add definitely doesn't work. On the layer of the initial strokes, it makes everything disappear and on a different layer, it just lightens the color of the initial strokes.

Comment: Try resetting your brush. Window>Brushes>Reset Brushes. Please don't down vote if it was you.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I appreciate anyone trying to help.

Comment: @ReotheNew Thanks, Did the resetting the brush work?

Comment: No, I'm already using it with default settings.

Comment: Post a screenshot of Photoshop

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem, after i recognized my brush painting mode was on "multiply" instead of "normal" . After I changed it everything was ok.